# Gradle IntelliJ add java dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have created new Gradle Java project on IntelliJ and added the library like normally do in Android Studio.

Gradle is not getting the library and compiling it.

[image]

Build file.

```
group 'asynjava'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.x.y"

}
```

I couldn't import the library inside my java files. 
Is there any settings I have missed ?

Comment: The file is not there, the red text

Comment: Yes. after I add the library  inside build script. IDE should get it automatically ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.2'
```

You have to specify the complete version info, the minor version numbers in particular.